# QT Creator - Unable to build HTML5 application

Tags: c++, html, qt-creator

I just installed QT Creator 2.7.0 [Based on Qt 5.0.1 (64 bit)] on my Ubuntu 13.04 end. I tried creating a sample HTML5 Application and when I try to run it, some issues are encountered. Here's the output of the build process.

```
23:16:22: Starting: "/usr/bin/qmake" /home/res/Git/test/first/first.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64 CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
23:16:22: The process "/usr/bin/qmake" exited normally.
23:16:22: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
make: Circular all <- first dependency dropped.
Copying application data...
g++ -m64 -o first main.o html5applicationviewer.o moc_html5applicationviewer.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQt5WebKitWidgets -lX11 -lxslt -lrt -lgio-2.0 -lgstapp-0.10 -lgstinterfaces-0.10 -lgstpbutils-0.10 -pthread -lgstvideo-0.10 -lgstbase-0.10 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lxml2 -lglib-2.0 -lsqlite3 -L/build/buildd/qtdeclarative-opensource-src-5.0.1/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/build/buildd/qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.0.1/lib -lQt5Sql -lQt5Quick -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5WebKit -lQt5Qml -lQt5Location -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Sensors -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxslt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstapp-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstinterfaces-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstpbutils-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstvideo-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstbase-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstreamer-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmodule-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [first] Error 1
23:16:22: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project first (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
23:16:22: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

This is the first time I'm trying this HTML5 application in QT Creator. 
How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each library, check if you've installed appropriate *-dev package. E.g for message `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxslt` check package `libxslt1-dev`

Comment: Thanks! Installing the dev packages for missing libraries worked